# How to disable an event observer defined by default in Magento2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, up-sells

I would like to disable an event observer attached to certain event in default magento.

The `Magento\Bundle\Observer\AppendUpsellProductsObserver` observer is attached to the event `catalog_product_upsell` which I want to disable as it is showing products I don't want to show in Upsell.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If we take a look at:

**vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php**

```
 public function dispatch(array $configuration, Observer $observer)
    {
        /** Check whether event observer is disabled */
        if (isset($configuration['disabled']) && true === $configuration['disabled']) {
            return;
        }

        if (isset($configuration['shared']) && false === $configuration['shared']) {
            $object = $this->_observerFactory->create($configuration['instance']);
        } else {
            $object = $this->_observerFactory->get($configuration['instance']);
        }
        $this->_callObserverMethod($object, $observer);
    }
```

We can see how to share and disable a Event Observer. So, in our custom module, we can disable the Event Observer Magento default.

For example, we're going to disable `wishlist_add_product` event in report module **vendor/magento/module-reports/etc/frontend/events.xml**

Our **Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="wishlist_add_product">
        <observer name="reports" disabled="true"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

The event name and observer name are the same Magento default.

Comment: super....... +1

Answer (score 11):

Did some digging and seems its actually pretty easy to disable a certain event observer in Magento2.

All we have to do, is create a custom module and add a events.xml file to the same area where the event observer is attached, and add the following line:

```
<observer name="[observer _name]" disabled="true"/>
```

So in my case the event observer xml was at `vendor/magento/module-bundle/etc/frontend/events.xml`, so this means the `area` was frontend.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_upsell">
        <observer name="bundle_observer" instance="Magento\Bundle\Observer\AppendUpsellProductsObserver"/>
    </event>
    ......
</config>
```

Thats means in our custom module we create a `events.xml` at lets say `app/code/Foo/Bar/etc/frontend/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <!-- Disabling Default Observer Magento\Bundle\Observer\AppendUpsellProductsObserver -->
    <event name="catalog_product_upsell">
        <observer name="bundle_observer" disabled="true"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

> Note: Here the observer `name` and the event `name` should be the same as used in default
>   magento

That about does the trick.