# Keep the product in wishlist after the product added to the cart

Tags: magento-2.1, addtocart, wishlist

When I add the product to the cart at the wishlist page, the product automatically removed from the wishlist and the product was no longer in the wishlist page. Is there a way to keep the product at a wishlist after adding the product to the cart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, I cannot find the best solution for this case. My idea is to disable wishlist event (and then we can create our custom event):

```
<event name="checkout_cart_add_product_complete">
    <observer name="wishlist" disabled="true"/>
</event>
```

Comment: so i need to override the observer?

Comment: @IdhamChoudry https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/130084/33057

Comment: I tried this solution but not work for me.

Comment: @Ketan I have checked. It should work.

Comment: @Khoa Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 0):

Here are solution which can be solved your problem:

Note: Please Override below functions which i mentioned because of best practices :)

vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php

```
public function execute()
{
   /** Comment this event */
   /*$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
            ['product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse()]
        );*/ 
}
```

vendor/magento/module-wishlist/Controller/Index/Cart.php

```
/** Make this change */
$item->addToCart($this->cart, true);
To
$item->addToCart($this->cart, false);
```

Hope this can be helpful.

Happy coding :)

Thanks